# When to use Lucene/Hibernate Search

Tags: mysql, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I am working on an application where we have different types of Searches.Some of them are full text searches over multiple columns in a MYSQL database and i am using Hibernate Search(which uses lucene internally ) for these.

Now my question is What to do in case of simple database searches which are not full text.A search of the form :

```
select * from table1,table2 where table1.col1='testval' and table1.col2=table2.col2;
```

Will such search be better if i use hibernate search or would there be no effect on performance,since this is not a full text search

Comment: You should probably rewrite that SQL query as a `join`, by the way.

Comment: Any reason to downvote ?

Comment: There's a whole load of stupid downvoting that goes on round here on perfectly sensible questions. Not much you can do other than ignore it. I'm upvoting this question to cancel out the silliness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will certainly get a performance improvement using Lucene / Hibernate Search. The reason is that it will maintain an index locally, and then use that for the search, rather than having to query the database to retrieve the results, so it will reduce your network traffic and reduce the load on the database.

Of course, for a simple application with network and database under a light load, you won't necessarily notice any difference, but when things start to scale up, you'll notice. The more you can do to avoid unnecessary database queries, the better.

Comment: So if we do plan to scale the application to let's say around a million users,with active searches ,would you advice making all searches Hibernate/Lucene based as it will give us an edge in performance